# Scroll to div from li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twig

I have a symfony view which looks like this

```
{% for menu in menus %}
<li>{{menu.name}}</li>
```

I want to be able to go on a specific div when I click to the li element.

Here is the full simplified page:

```
{% for menu in menus %}
    <li>{{menu.name}}</li>
{% endfor %}
<p id="generalAnchor">Some text</p>
//And here i include some view depending on the li element clicked.
```

But in fact, when depending on the imported view size, the page is not really pretty.

So I want to scroll directly to the generalAnchor element.
I know I can do this with `a` and `href` but here I need to work with the `li` and I don't know what method I can use.

Comment: you realize you dont need any javascript for that, right ? a simple <a href="#anchorname"> to point the link to a <a name="anchorname"> will suffice. its plain old html.

Comment: You link to an anchor `<a href="#generalAnchor">link text</a>`, so nothing changes other then your list item content `<a..>{{ menu.name }}</a>`?

Comment: I said i can't use something as simple as a a href link...i know i can do it this way; but in that specific case i can't use a link to go on the anchor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use jquery to scroll to the div.

```
 $("li").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#generalAnchor").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: I'm going to try this, thanks. I will tell you if this is working.

Comment: Works fine thanks. I just have a doubt with what i will get with some mobile device as android or iphone. But i think it will be ok.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a click event listener on your `li`  items and use the pure Javascript [scrollIntoView](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_scrollintoview.asp) method. 
Something like `document.getElementById("generalAnchor").scrollIntoView()` should do the trick.

Of course, using JQuery would help you to do it smoothly with the [JQuery.scrollTo](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo) plugin

Answer (score 0):

Just put an anchor tag in each list item. You can bind each link to a specific id by using something like this:

```
<li><a href="#{{menu.id}}">{{menu.name}}</a></li>
```

And then you just need to give your corresponding elements you want to scroll to the right matching ids.

Comment: The OP said he can't use anchors

Comment: I said that :D (Maybe with an awfull english).